# Limiting what to join over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to count a subset of lines of a table over a many-to-many relationships (tag-tags-post), using SQLite. I have attempted the following SQL without luck:

```
SELECT tag.*, count(post.id)
FROM tag 
JOIN tags 
   ON tag.id = tags.tag_id 
JOIN post 
   ON post.id = tags.post_id 
   AND datetime(post.published) < datetime('2012-08-08 12:42:41.696451') 
GROUP BY tag.id, tag.name, tag.description, tag.slug 
ORDER BY tag.name
```

I have tried moving the condition to a `WHERE` clause but that changes nothing. Without the condition, the result is shown as expected.

**EDIT 1**

Just ot be clear, by removing the `AND` condition I get results, albeit with all rows of `post`, as expected. Furthermore, the following query

```
SELECT count(post.id) 
FROM post 
WHERE datetime(post.published) < datetime('2012-08-08 12:42:41.696451')
```

Delivers the correct result.

**EDIT 2**

There was a data entry error in the tags table. The query is now working fine. Apologies to everyone. Voted to delete.

Comment: You can't do WHERE GROUP BY. I assume that's a typo?

Comment: Indeed, I have removed that. Thank you.

Comment: No results returned @ypercube.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT tag.id, tag.name, tag.description, tag.slug, count(post.id)
FROM tag JOIN
     tags 
     ON tag.id = tags.tag_id JOIN
     post 
     ON post.id = tags.post_id AND
        datetime(post.published) < datetime('2012-08-08 12:42:41.696451') 
GROUP BY tag.id, tag.name, tag.description, tag.slug
ORDER BY tag.name
```

The original SQL would generate an error if tag had any columns other than the four in the group by.  It is possible, though, that to get what you want, that you need:  COUNT(DISTINCT post.id).

Check if the original joins are working by doing right outer joins instead of joins:

```
SELECT tag.id, tag.name, tag.description, tag.slug, count(post.id)
FROM tag right outer JOIN
     tags 
     ON tag.id = tags.tag_id right outer JOIN
     post 
     ON post.id = tags.post_id AND
        datetime(post.published) < datetime('2012-08-08 12:42:41.696451') 
GROUP BY tag.id, tag.name, tag.description, tag.slug
ORDER BY tag.name
```

If you get a row where the first four columns are NULL, then your ids are not matching between the tables.

Comment: This delivers no results unfortunately.

Comment: This query is using the joins set up in your original query.  Presumably, there is an issue with the join from tag to tags or from tags to post.  You can try outer joins to see if this is a problem.

Comment: Gordon, using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` delivers a result, albeit an incorrect  (0 rows for each tag), suggesting that no rows in `post` match my condition. However, as per my edit, there are in fact rows which match the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have too much precision in your date?

Ie: does this work

```
SELECT tag.*, count(post.id) 
FROM tag  
JOIN tags  
   ON tag.id = tags.tag_id  
JOIN post  
   ON post.id = tags.post_id  
   AND datetime(post.published) < datetime('2012-08-08 12:42:41')  
GROUP BY tag.id, tag.name, tag.description, tag.slug  
ORDER BY tag.name
```

Comment: And you have posts with tags published before that time...?

Comment: Yes. The chosen column, `post.published`, is just an example. Trying to filter the rows of `post` seems to result in no rows every time.

Comment: I think we need to see some sample data. I've created some of my own, and the sql is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is some problem with the casting. I'm not sure if need the cast to `DATETIME`.

Try this with inner joins replaced with left joins, This will at least show all tags with 0 counts if no post match the conditions:

```
SELECT tag.*, COUNT(DISTINCT post.id)
FROM tag 
  LEFT JOIN tags 
    ON  tag.id = tags.tag_id 
  LEFT JOIN post 
    ON  post.id = tags.post_id 
    AND post.published < '2012-08-08 12:42:41.696451' 
GROUP BY tag.id, tag.name, tag.description, tag.slug 
ORDER BY tag.name ;
```

Try also with chopping the time to millseconds:  `'2012-08-08 12:42:41.696'` or to seconds:  `'2012-08-08 12:42:41'`

Comment: Indeed, this shows all tag with 0 results. However, there __are__ rows which match the condition, as per my edit to the question.

Comment: @nobRuked: see my edit. Anyway, can you post a few rows from the 3 tables (that match the condiitons)?